# Renaming a TeamCity server hostname

Tags: teamcity

I am using TeamCity 6.5.4 and i'd like to rename the server (hostname).

I've seen other applications that cannot handle this, as the hostname is used internally by databses, configuration files, etc.

Is this possible? Can i just rename through Windows and be done with it ?

Also asked on this forum: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/312790?tstart=0
Thanks
Lior Tal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing which I am aware of is the connection of the agents. If you specified the hostname for this, you have to change it in the agent config after renaming the host.

Everything else should be fine with the rename. 
Best practise therefore is to use an alias for the hostname, which doesn't change.

Comment: Thanks. Is this based on personal experience? btw: when upgrading a TeamCity server to a new version, it seems to uninstall and install the new version if i'm not mistaken. Is this correct? if so, i may use this opportunity to rename the server & reinstall...

Comment: Yes. I can't remember any issues. You are correct, an upgrade means uninstall and install. Would be an ideal moment for your change, as you also have to reconfigure your agent(s)